# Setup Cassandra for Django - "python manage.py sync_cassandra" or "sudo python manage.py sync_cassandra"

Tags: django, cassandra, pycassa

I'm following guide in https://github.com/thobbs/twissandra

I'm still stuck at:

```
cd twissandra
python manage.py sync_cassandra
```

`python manage.py sync_cassandra` will generate

```
['/home/z/twissandra', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8.2-py2.6.egg', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycassa-1.0.5-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.5.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/z/twissandra/tweets/management/commands/sync_cassandra.py", line 16, in handle_noargs
    sys.describe_keyspace('Twissandra')
AttributeError: 'SystemManager' object has no attribute 'describe_keyspace'
```

`sudo python manage.py sync_cassandra` will generate

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/z/twissandra/tweets/management/commands/sync_cassandra.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pycassa
ImportError: No module named pycassa
```

yes, that was errors..
But I'm a bit confuse, `sudo` or not `sudo`...
`python manage.py sync_cassandra` or `sudo python manage.py sync_cassandra`

Answer (score 1):

Solved. without `sudo` is the right. It will use python version from virtual environment